# How do I choose a proof technique to prove graph properties

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

This question comes from an undergrad graph theory course.

I am asked to prove that, for a graph $G = (V, E)$ with maximum degree $\Delta$, $|E| \leq |V| \cdot ({\Delta}/{2})$.

I can do enough examples to convince myself that this is true, but I'm struggling with a formal proof.

Without separable conditions, I don't think it suits a direct proof. I've not figured out a way to prove by contradiction.

The most promising I thought of was proof by induction (so prove it for a graph where $|V| = 1, 2, k, k+1$). This seems like it might not work though, as it doesn't take into account all of the possible values of $\Delta$.

Can anyone suggest a proof technique or another starting point?

Comment: A starting point: find an expression for the number of edges in terms of the degrees of the vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is not really possible to know, which proof-technique will work out. For formulas in terms of number of vertices, number of edges, degrees, number of components etc. there usually are three approaches:

1. Use induction (in this case it doesn’t really make sense, as you admitted)
2. Use contradiction (start with a graph contradicting the claim and see what happens)
3. Use a more general / more specific result (in this case there is a more specific formula of number of edges in terms of degrees of vertices, as was mentioned in the comments, sometimes called the handshake lemma)

Of cause there might be more elaborate ways required to prove the result (not in this case), but I think these are the standard approaches...